# Populating datagridview using asynchronous callback and thread mechanism

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am new to .NET. I need to complete the following assignment using asynchronous callback mechanism in C# winforms.

On a form load I need to get the data from database and populate in a datagridview. The retrieval may take a long time and I want to use the UI meanwhile. Also I need a callback mechanism to check whether datagridview is populated or not. I have to use thread and async callback mechanism to achieve this.

```
    private CustomerEntities cn = null;

    delegate CustomerEntities DataSourceDelegate();
    delegate void loadGridViewDelegate(CustomerEntities dtCustomers);

    DataSourceDelegate delegate_GetCustomers;

    public CustomerEntities DataSource()
    {
        cn = new CustomerEntities();
        return cn;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        status.Text = "Loading";
        delegate_GetCustomers = new DataSourceDelegate(DataSource);
        delegate_GetCustomers.BeginInvoke(LoadCustomerCallBack, null);
    }

    private void LoadCustomerCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        CustomerEntities dtCutomers;
        dtCutomers = delegate_GetCustomers.EndInvoke(ar);
        loadGridView(dtCutomers);
    }

    private void loadGridView(CustomerEntities dtCutomers)
    {
        if (dataGridView.InvokeRequired)
        {
            loadGridViewDelegate del = new loadGridViewDelegate(loadGridView);
            dataGridView.Invoke(del, new CustomerEntities[] { dtCutomers });
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView.DataSource = dtCutomers.customerDetails;
        }
    }
```

The datagridview is getting populated correctly but the UI is blocked when I'm trying to access it when the function is retrieving the data.

Comment: OK we got what you need but what is your question?

Comment: @I4V: Since I am new to .NET, I need the steps involved to achieve this

Comment: You are obviously taking a course/class and while stackoverflow is a great source for knowledge on the subjects you describe, its intent isent solving your entire assignments. The best solution is to try some coding yourself then when/if you need help come back and ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute any code that modifies a WinForm control on the main thread. Use this type of pattern in your callback:

```
private void CallbackHandler (object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (InvokeRequired)
     {
         Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { CallbackHandler (sender, e); });
         return;
     }

     // If you get here, you are running on the main thread.
 }
```

Edit: As for the actual Async 'getting the data' your database library will very likely have a function that accepts a callback as one of its arguments. This will handle everything else for you.

To handle the threading by hand simply make a task:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew ( () =>
{
    FunctionThatTakesALongTime();
    CallbackHandler();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
myWindow.BeginInvoke(new My_Main.ProductDelegate(myWindow.PopulateGrid), new object[] { row });
```

However, you should only use Invoke / BeginInvoke if your code is running on a background thread.

If your UpdateProducts method runs on the UI thread, you don't need BeginInvoke; you can simply call the method normally, like this:

```
myWindow.PopulateGrid(row);
```

If you do call BeginInvoke, you need to create a separate array instance in each iteration by moving the declaration of row inside the loop.